# get application names of AT jobs from scheduled tasks

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

How can I get a list of all the AT scheduled tasks' application names?

But I want to know how to do it exactly by using function `NetScheduleJobGetInfo` and `AT_INFO` Structure?

I'm programming in C++

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you have the wrong function.  You should be looking at [`NetScheduleJobEnum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb706691.aspx) which will give you an array of [`AT_ENUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb720767.aspx) structs, one for each job. Inside `AT_ENUM` is the command associated with the task.